# Повтор php скрипта

Tags: php

Есть крон, но он может запускать скрипт не чаще чем раз в минуту.
Так вот как сделать так, чтобы крон запускал скрипт, а он самоповторялся 5 раз через 10 секунд до следующего запуска кроном?

Comment: `watch --interval=5 /var/Ваш скрипт`

Answer (score 0):

Можно организовать следующим образом. Скрипт не запускает сам себя, но я думаю это лишнее.

```
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++) {
        //нужная логика

        sleep(10);
    }
```

Comment: $i = 5;
$pause = 10; 
while ( $i > 0){ скрипт
sleep($pause);
$i--;
}

Такой вариант рабочий?

Comment: а можно пример?

Comment: @ChinaBelarus Вполне, но я думаю, что дучше поменять логику вашей программы, чтобы не пользоваться такими извращениями.

Comment: нельзя поменять, нужно чтобы проверка скриптом была каждые 10-15 секунд

Comment: @ChinaBelarus Эмм, ну вот вам пример

`        $file = 'test.txt';

        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++)
        {
            $str = date('H:m:s') . ' index - ' . $i . PHP_EOL;
            file_put_contents($file, $str,FILE_APPEND);
            sleep(5);
        }`